# pasar variable PHP entre páginas con JSON y AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

Estoy haciendo un código que me permita enviar una variable PHP de una página web a otra sin formulario. He visto algunos tutoriales y algunos códigos. Con lo poco que sé, creo que hay que decodificar la variable con JSON primero. La idea es alojar una cadena de valores en una variable PHP a través de un bucle for, y con JSON y Ajax reenviar esa cadena. Por lo que pude ver, en este caso no serían necesarias variables super globales. De cualquier forma, no puedo hacer andar el código.

pagina1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Problema</title>
  <script src="funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Recuperar variables PHP con JSON a través de json_encode</h2>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Recuperar" id="boton1">
  <div id="resultados"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

funciones.js

```
addEventListener('load',inicializarEventos,false);

function inicializarEventos()
{
  var ob=document.getElementById('boton1');
  ob.addEventListener('click',presionBoton,false);
}

var conexion1;
function presionBoton(e)
{
  conexion1=new XMLHttpRequest();
  conexion1.onreadystatechange = procesarEventos;
  conexion1.open('GET','pagina1.php', true);
  conexion1.send();
}

function procesarEventos()
{
  var resultados = document.getElementById("resultados");
  if(conexion1.readyState == 4)
  {

    var datos1=json_encode($a);
    var datos2=JSON_parse(datos1);  
    resultados.innerHTML = datos2;
  } 
  else 
  {
    resultados.innerHTML = "Cargando...";
  }
}
```

pagina1.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/txt; charset=utf-8');

for($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++) {
    $var=json_encode($a);    
}

echo $var;
```

Comment: No lo tomes a mal, pero creo que te estaría faltando una buena base en PHP y JS. Tu código tiene errores que asumo son por falta de conocimiento sobre el uso de [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) de PHP y las APIs [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest) y [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) de Javascript

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Creo que lo de que es un poco novato ya lo deja claro en el enunciado _Con lo poco que sé_. No es que te esté echado la bronca, sino que quiero dejar un simple comentario como aporte. Creo que este tipo de usuarios son los que hay que mantener en stackoverflow  ya que la pregunta está muy bien formulada y con ejemplos del código que tiene actualmente. Creo que tu comentario es muy bueno con las referencias a las documentaciones, sin embargo, siendo nuevo muchas veces es difícil descubrir el error. Creo que deberías de escribir una respuesta indicándole dónde tiene sus fallos.

Comment: Así es, soy novato en estas materias, pero decidí investigar por mi cuenta basándome en http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/ajaxya/index.php    Me propuse pasar una variable PHP entre páginas web. Me parece que la pregunta está bien planteada. Siendo un novato, no sé si es necesario pasar una variable PHP por JSON. Como Ajax se llama desde JavaScript, me parece razonable codificar una variable PHP al lenguaje de JavaScript. No sé si bastará con usar variables globales. Toda sugerencia es bienvenida.

Answer (score 3):

En la parte de Javascript te falta evaluar *Status* de la petición para saber si fue exitosa ( 200 ).

El valor enviado por la página de php se guarda en la propiedad *responseText* en conexion1 y no sólo aparece con el mismo nombre como lo intentas recuperar en `var datos1=json_encode($a);`

La funcion json_encode es propia de php y la sintaxis de JSON_parse es incorrecta, los metodos equivalentes son los siguientes

JSON.stringify(Obj) -> convierte un objeto en una cadena de texto

JSON.parse(StrignObj) -> convierte una cadena de texto a un objeto, ésta cadena  debe tener un formato específico generado con JSON.stringify en js o con json_encode en php.

En php, asumiendo que quieres enviar los valores concatenados dentro del ciclo debes cambiar la siguiente linea

`$var=json_encode($a);`

a

`$var .= $a;`

Al agregar el punto haces que el valor se "agregue" a lo que ya tenia guardada la variable en lugar de reemplazarlo. Al final el valor de *$var* seria igual a 012

Regresar el resultado puedes crear un array con el valor y hacer json_encode

`echo json_encode(array('resultado' => $var ))`

lo cuál dará como resultado el siguiente objeto

```
{
  "resultado":012
}
```

Ahora para recuperar la información en js

```
if(conexion1.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && conexion1.status === 200) {
        var a = JSON.parse(conexion1.responseText);
        resultados.innerHTML = a.resultado;

 }
```

Prueba haciendo estas pequeñas modificaciones

Comment: gracias Marcos Gallardo y Eduardo Obregón

Answer (score 2):

Tu código tiene errores con respecto al uso de [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) de PHP, la API [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest) y el objecto [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON) de Javascript

Partiendo del enunciado:

> La idea es alojar una cadena de valores en una variable PHP a través de un bucle for, y con JSON y Ajax reenviar esa cadena.

**// Errores:**

- Si analizamos el archivo **pagina1.php**:

  1. El `header` para una respuesta JSON no es el correcto.
  2. El el bucle `for`, no se esta *generando una cadena de valores* (ej: "012") ya que tampoco se estan `concatenando`, se esta pisando el valor de `$var` en cada iteración. Lo que se esta generando es *una cadena de texto JSON* (ej: "2").
- Si analizamos el archivo **funciones.js**:

  1. Dentro de la función `procesarEventos`, podemos ver que te estaría faltando, evaluar el `status` de `conexion1`, la variable `$a` y los métodos `json_encode` y `JSON_parse` no están declarados y tampoco forman parte de la funciones `nativas` del navegador.

**// Solución:**

Considerando todo lo enunciado anteriormente, una posible solución a tu código, podría ser:

**pagina1.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

// Inicializamos $var
$var = '';
for($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++) {
    // Concatenamos los valores de $a
    $var .= $a;    
}

// Imprimimos en formato JSON un arreglo 
// (para justificar usar JSON.parse en el cliente) 
// con el valor de $var en la posición 'variable'
echo json_encode(array('variable'=> $var));
```

**funciones.js**

```
addEventListener('load',inicializarEventos,false);

function inicializarEventos() {
  var ob=document.getElementById('boton1');
  ob.addEventListener('click',presionBoton,false);
}

var conexion1;
function presionBoton(e) {
  conexion1=new XMLHttpRequest();
  conexion1.onreadystatechange = procesarEventos;
  conexion1.open('GET','pagina1.php', true);
  conexion1.send();
}

function procesarEventos() {
  var resultados = document.getElementById("resultados");

  // Controlamos el estado de la respuesta
  if(conexion1.readyState == 4 && conexion1.status == 200) {
    // Obtenemos el texto de la respuesta
    var respuesta = conexion1.responseText;

    // Decodificamos la respuesta codificada en JSON
    var json = JSON.parse(respuesta);

    // Imprimimos el valor de `variable`
    resultados.innerHTML = json.variable;
  } 
  else 
  {
    resultados.innerHTML = "Cargando...";
  }
}
```