# ERROR: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estoy creando una pequeña pagina web que estoy probando localmente y al hora de mandar mis datos al código de php todo esta bien pero cuando php le responde al código de javascript me sale el error del titulo

Código de php:

```
<?php 
    require_once "conexion.php";
    $conexion=conexion();


    $contar="select count(*) from usuarios";
    $numReg=mysqli_query($conexion,$contar);
    if ($numReg) {
        $f1 = mysqli_fetch_row($numReg);
        $idU=generarID($f1[0],"A");
    }

    $id=$idU;
    $rol=3;
    $m=$_POST['matricula'];
    $n=$_POST['nombre'];
    $aP=$_POST['apeP'];
    $aM=$_POST['apeM'];
    $t=$_POST['tel'];
    $c=$_POST['correo'];
    $p=$_POST['pais'];
    $e=$_POST['escuela'];
    $pS=$_POST['pass'];
    mysqli_free_result($numReg);

    $sql="INSERT into usuarios (matricula,contrasena,idUsuario,rol)
                                values ('$m','$pS','$id','$rol');";

    $sql.="INSERT into alumno (id_Usuario,nombres,apeP,apeM,telefono,correo,pais,escuela)
                                values ('$id','$n','$aP','$aM','$t','$c','$p','$e');";

    $result=mysqli_multi_query($conexion,$sql);


    if ($result) {
        echo json_encode(array('respuesta' => true, 'msg' => 'Se ingresaron con exito los datos'));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('respuesta' => false, 'msg' => 'ERROR'));
    }



    function generarID($reg,$letra){
        $reg++;
        for ($i=1; $i < 5; $i++) { 
            $numero=rand(0,9);
            $letra.=$numero;
        }
        return $letra."-".$reg;
    }

 ?>
```

Como pueden ver ni si quiera genero el JSON yo, uso directamente `json_encode()`

```
var enviar = function(e){
    if (!validarInputs()) {
        console.log('Falto validar los Input');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (!validarSelect()) {
        console.log('Falto validar el select');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        var datos=new FormData(form);
        xhr.open('POST','../basedatos/php/agregarDatos.php');

        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status==200) {
            }else{
                alert("ERROR AL ESTABLECER CONEXION");
            }
        }
        xhr.send(datos);

        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if(response.respuesta == true ){
            alert(response.msg);
        }else{
            alert(response.msg);
        }

    }
};
```

Esta es la parte del código que da el error pero no se porque, ya verifique que el JSON que se esta mandando tenga el formato correcto pero aun así me sigue mandando el mismo error, este es el JSON que se genera

```
{"respuesta":false,"msg":"Se ingresaron con éxito los datos"}
```

Comment: Estás ejecutando una llamada asíncrona y los datos no estarán disponibles hasta que finalice. Busca ejemplos, como este: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34443/pasar-variable-php-entre-p%c3%a1ginas-con-json-y-ajax

Comment: Pon el error que te da

Comment: es el del titulo: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @PrecastCrib6 revertí tu edición pues no es correcto ni válido publicar la solución en la misma pregunta, para ello dispones abajo de la zona de respuestas o que aceptes la respuesta (si alguna de las otorgadas te fue de ayuda)

Answer (score 0):

Si de verdad necesitas que tu JSON se respete con sus tipos de dato correctos, vas a tener que utilizar una cabecera en PHP para que, incluso, la lectura del JSON no tenga que ser parseada y sea un objeto JSON nativo retornado. Muestro ejemplo:

Retorna de esta manera utilizando la cabecera de tipo json en PHP como:

```
if ($result) {
    $response = json_encode(array('respuesta' => true, 'msg' => 'Se ingresaron con exito los datos'));
} else {
    $response = json_encode(array('respuesta' => false, 'msg' => 'ERROR'));
}

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Y tu código javascript debe de ser modificado de tal forma de que lo utilices sin convertir o parsear de manera nativa como objeto JSON:

```
var response = xhr.responseText;
if(response.respuesta == true ){
    alert(response.msg);
}else{
    alert(response.msg);
}
```

Bonus:

Utilizar el valor `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` como segundo parámetro de la función json_encode es solo para darle una presentación más formal y limpia al JSON. Encuentra más información en la documentación oficial de PHP

Comment: Gracias por contestar, el error se ha solucionado, pero ahora en el alert me sale **undefined** es como si en el mensaje de respuesta no hubiera nada

Comment: podrías decirme o actualizar tu pregunta para saber ahora el nuevo problema? porque no sé si estés sacando bien el valor de msg y sea un nuevo problema

Answer (score 0):

No veo donde estás instanciando el xhr, pero suponiendo que en alguna parte tengas

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Hay un problema en la secuencia de eventos:

```
   xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status==200) {
          // recién acá habrá resultados
        }else{
            alert("ERROR AL ESTABLECER CONEXION");
        }
    }
    xhr.send(datos);

    // aquí todavía no hay resultados
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (response.respuesta == true ){
        alert(response.msg);
    } else{
        alert(response.msg);
    }
```

Debiera ser, en cambio

```
   xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status==200) {
          var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          if (response.respuesta == true ){
            alert(response.msg);
          } else {
            alert(response.msg);
          }
        } else {
            alert("ERROR AL ESTABLECER CONEXION");
        }
    }
    xhr.send(datos);
```

Además, como te dijo Fernando Urban, está el tema de la cabecera Content Type en el PHP

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar el problema se hicieron cambios en ambos códigos:

PHP:

```
if ($result) {
        $response = array('respuesta' => true, 'msg' => 'Se ingresaron con exito los datos');
    } else {
        $response = array('respuesta' => false, 'msg' => 'ERROR');
    }

    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Javascript:

```
xhr.open('POST','../basedatos/php/agregarDatos.php');

        xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status==200) {
          var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          if (response.respuesta == true ){
            alert(response.msg);
          } else {
            alert(response.msg);
          }
        } else {
            alert("ERROR AL ESTABLECER CONEXION");
        }
    }
    xhr.send(datos);
```